# Solve $2^{\left(\log_2\sqrt{x^2-6x+9}\right)} = 3^{\log_\sqrt{x}(x-1)}$ for real $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve
>   $$
> 2^{\left(\log_2\sqrt{x^2-6x+9}\right)}
> = 3^{\log_\sqrt{x}(x-1)}
> $$
>   for any real $x$.

I am unable to solve it completely, the farthest I went (for $x \in (0,3)$) was $\log(x)\cdot \log(3-x) = \log(x-1) \cdot \log(9)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The LHS simplifies to $|x-3|$ but I don't see the purpose of RHS ? $x=2$ is trivial root though, but the other one...

Comment: I know it has 2 roots, but couldn't figure out any of them/ how do you get that 2?

Comment: There are two solutions, one is $x=2$ and one is approximately $x=11.27$.

Comment: yeah but how do you get those roots, I mean can you get them algebraically .because I don't know how to graph this by hand (without any second source)

Answer (score 1):

Use $a^{\log_a x}=x$, then we get $$\sqrt{x^2-6x+9}=3^{\log_{\sqrt{x}} (x-1)}\implies |x-3|=
3^{\log_{\sqrt{x}}(x-1)}.$$ The root can be found by ispection only and it is $x=2.$

Comment: thank you for answering.
what does by inspection mean, by guessing? can you prove that $x=2$ algebraically? the biggest problem is the second root, can you find it?
p.s. sorry for so many questions :))

Comment: Sorry I don't know how else to find it.

Comment: thank you mate, I am new to MSE and don't know how to write things I want to ask.
so thank you anyway, you are my first respondent.

Answer (score 1):

If you plot the function
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-6 x+9}-3^{\frac{\log (x-1)}{\log \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}}$$ you can notice tht the second root is close to $x=11$.

So, make a Taylor expansion  around $x=9$ to have nice numbers to get
$$f(x)=-2+\frac{12  \log (2)}{9 \log (3)}(x-9)+O\left((x-9)^2\right)$$
Ignoring the higher order terms, an *approximation* is
$$x=9+\frac{3\log(3)}{2\log(2)}\approx 11.3774$$ while the "exact" solution could be obtained very fast starting at this value.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 11.377443751081734272 \\
 1 & 11.272854680548284363 \\
 2 & 11.272737325369640493 \\
 3 & 11.272737325218626553
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: but how can you graph this function by hand ??

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$\begin{align*}
  2^{\log_2 \sqrt{x^2 -6 x + 9}}
      &= 3^{\log_{\sqrt{x}}(x-1)} \\
  \sqrt{(x - 3)^2}
      &= 3^{\log_3 (x - 1) / \log_3 \sqrt{x}} \\
  \lvert x - 3 \rvert
      &= (x - 1)^{2/ \log_3 x} \\
  \lvert x - 3 \rvert^{\log_3 x}
      &= (x - 1)^2
\end{align*}$

This is as far as simplification of the mess takes you. Now you have to switch to analyze cases. First off, $x > 0$, as otherwise the logarithm makes no sense. Need to consider $0 < x \le 1$, $1< x \le 3$, $x > 3$ separately. Perhaps plot the functions to see how they behave to see how to prove there is no/one/more zeros in each range.

Comment: so algebraically you can't go any far? Do you have to use graphing to see the result?

Comment: @alexnat009, a graph can tell you how the functions behave in general terms, hinting at what you should try to prove.

Comment: yea I know, but my problem is that I can't prove algebraically that this equation has 2 roots (2 and 11.27) and graphs hints can't help me :))

Comment: @alexnat009, then you have specific ranges over which to prove the function is decreasing/increasing (use derivatives!) and where you have values less/greater than zero at judiciously chosen points.