# From $x^N = x-1$, what can I deduce as to $N$? as to $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

In order to solve this question :

[Solve $2^{\left(\log_2\sqrt{x^2-6x+9}\right)} = 3^{\log_\sqrt{x}(x-1)}$ for real $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581711/solve-2-left-log-2-sqrtx2-6x9-right-3-log-sqrtxx-1-for-real/3581794#3581794)

I would like to know whether anything can be deduced from the fact that the number $\log_x(x-1)$ is defined, that is, from the fact that there is a number N such that $x^N = x-1$.

Can consequences be drawn from this: (1) as to $N$? (2) as to $x$?

The only consequence that seems sure to me is that N cannot be equal to one. For in that case $x^N$ = $x$ , which is not equal to $(x-1)$.

Comment: The function $N(x):=\log_x(x-1)=\tfrac{\ln(x-1)}{\ln(x)}$ is well-defined for all $x>1$. Clearly $N(x)<1$, and with some basic calculus it is easy to show that $N(x)$ is a continuous monotonically increasing bijection between $\Bbb{R}_{>1}$ and $\Bbb{R}_{<1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We study consequences from the definedness of $\log_x(x-1)$.

From the definition, we have that the base is positive and not $1$ and that the argument is positive.  (q.v. the first display at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm )\begin{align*}
x &> 0,  \\
x &\neq 1  \\
x-1 &> 0  \\
\end{align*}
Taken together, $x > 1$.

For $x > 1$, 
$$  \begin{cases} 
    x^N < x  ,&  N < 1  \\
    x^N = x  ,&  N = 1  \\
    x^N > x  ,&  N > 1
\end{cases}  \text{.}  $$
Since $x-1 < x$ for all $x$, the equation $x^N = x-1$, demands $x^N < x$, so $N < 1$.

Although from $x^N = x-1$, we have $x^N - x + 1 = 0$ looks like a polynomial, it is not unless $N = 0$ (and then $2 = x$) or $N=1$ (which is already excluded and which yields the contradiction $1 = 0$).

As $N$ approaches $1$ from below, $x^N$ more nearly approximates a straight line with slope $1$ and $y$-intercept $0$ (although it does slowly curve below this line).  This allows solutions with arbitrarily large $x$.

As $N$ approaches $0$ from above, $x^{N}$ more nearly approximates the constant function $1$, and as observed when studying the polynomial, $x$ more and more closely approximates $2$ from above.  When $N = 0$, $x = 2$.

As $N$ approaches $0$ from below, $x^N$ is positive and decreasing for $x > 1$ and less than $1$, so the solution has $1 < x < 2$.

If $N$ is a negative integer, $-n$, 
$$  x^{-n} = x-1  $$
can be solved by polynomial techniques.  For instance, $x^{-1} = x-1$ has solution $x = \frac{1}{2}(1 \pm \sqrt{5})$ (and we take "$+$" since we know $x > 1$).

As $N$ continues to descend, the curve $x^N$ descends more nearly vertically through the point $(x,x^N) = (1,1)$, and the value of $x$ decreases towards $1$.

Summarizing the last several observations, the inequalities $x>1$, $N < 1$ are sharp, since solutions are found for any choice satisfying either of these inequalities.